# Any base R function to display top left of matrix?

Tags: r

Example because I know I would be tarred and feathered without one.

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
b <- c(6,7,8,9,10)
d <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
e <- c(3,4,5,6,7)

abdc<-cbind(a,b,d,e)
abdc[1:3,1:3]
head(abdc)
tail(abdc)
```

What I am wondering is if there is a built in function for R that displays something similar to `head()` and `tail()` but works for matrices with many columns.

I have been finding myself typing in the matrix[1:10,1:10] too many times...

If there isn't a built in I will probably figure out how to add a function to my profile.  Any help with that would be great.

Comment: just write a wee function along the lines of `show_m <- function(mat, x) mat[1:x,1:x] ` ; try  `m <- matrix(1:36, 6) ; show_m(m, 3)` . for your profile... http://www.r-bloggers.com/fun-with-rprofile-and-customizing-r-startup/

Comment: Oh nice!  Feel free to submit post for answer